# Read an Excel file and execute a script on each returned line - NodeJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help me?
I have the following problem

I would like to read an excel file and, on each line, execute an automated code
I'm doing it this way, but it performs all the part of reading the variables before and when it arrives in the automated code it is already on the last line, even though both are inside the same for

```
// Read the Excel file inside the project

const readXlsxFile = require ('read-excel-file / node');
  readXlsxFile ('./ XLS Documents / XLS Reading File / Funds.xlsx'). then ((rows) => {
    
    for (var l = 0; l <rows.length; l ++) {
     const fundoAtual = rows [l];
      console.log (current fund);
      
      driver.then (driver => driver.get ('https://www37.bb.com.br/portalbb/cotaFundos/GFI9.bbx'))
        .then (() => driver.wait (until.elementLocated (By.xpath ("// * [@ id = 'form: comboFundos'] / option [text () = '" + current fund + "']")) , 3000))

    }
```

Comment: This is an issue about asynchrony in Javascript. The for loop keeps executing even when the promise is resolving, so when it's finally resolved it gets the value of current fund which is last at the time of resolution instead of waiting for all of them.

Consider using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: but how can i do this using for if if i then do then for the selenium driver? That's what I'm not able to do. I tried to create a function just for automation, but if I catch after that then in the function for a supposed error, it stops the entire code.